# Has a column in GQ?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is it acceptable to say: he/she has a column in GQ/Forbes/etc.

It sounds a bit unnatural to me.

Comment: Quite natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds fine to me. Here's an example from [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2017/may/08/the-sun-owner-in-discussions-with-kelvin-mackenzie-over-his-departure):

> Ferrari, who has a column in the Sunday Express, is a friend of MacKenzie